# Submit form using java script in struts

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom, struts

Here is my sample code. I am trying to submit a form using JavaScript. Below code snippet works in all the browsers except IE7 and IE8

```
function deleteFileName(filename){
    //alert("openPage called" + pageNumber);
    document.forms[0].action = "/DeleteFile.do?filename=" + filename;
    document.forms[0].name = "searchForm";
    document.forms[0].setAttribute("method", "post");
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Below is exact error message on `document.forms[0].acton.....` line

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Could you show your JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you should replace :

```
document.forms[0].action = "/DeleteFile.do?filename=" + filename;
```

with this :

```
document.forms[0].setAttribute("action", "/DeleteFile.do?filename=" + filename);
```